# java sql select and insert query for groups and subgroups

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have two tables in my database.One is called 
Table_join and it has fields

```
ID , NameOfObject,Address,Date
```

The second table is called Connection,and it has fields:

```
ID,IDofGroup,IDofSubgroup.
```

When I am inserting new record,It can be an object without a subgroup,something like Object1 on on its own,or it can be an Object2, and Object21 that is a subgroup of Object2 - in that case in the second table Connection I would insert id of the Object2 into IDofGroup,and ID of the Object21 into IDofSubgroup.

I want to search my table,so for example when I type in Object2,in the table I wanna see Object2 and its address and date,and Object21 and its date address.When I use inner join,I only get Object21 when I search Object2,not Object2 itself.

also,when I use inner join,i only get id from object21,I need to get the name also.

My select query is

```
String query = "SELECT * from table_join  INNER JOIN connection ON table_join.id = connection.id_IDofSubgroup WHERE NameOfObject=?";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Object2 and Object21 are stored in the `Table_join` table. That means you need to look at two different record from that table at the same time. That means you need that table in the `FROM`/`JOIN` clause *twice*.

Since you're returning two rows from the same table at the same time, your column names will clash, so you have to rename them in the query.

```sql
SELECT t1.ID           AS MainID
     , t1.NameOfObject AS MainName
     , t1.Address      AS MainAddress
     , t1.Date         AS MainDate
     , t2.ID           AS SubID
     , t2.NameOfObject AS SubName
     , t2.Address      AS SubAddress
     , t2.Date         AS SubDate
  FROM Table_join t1
  JOIN Connection c ON c.IDofGroup = t1.ID
  JOIN Table_join t2 ON t2.ID = c.IDofSubgroup
 WHERE t1.NameOfObject = ?
```

Comment: that still gives me only Object21,not Object2 also when I enter Object2 in the search. I wanna see in my result Object2 and Object 21.And in time I will have Object22,Object23..